# How to fix spark-shell on Windows (fails with "was unexpected at this time")?

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting following error when running spark-shell command:

[image]

I have downloaded `spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz` file from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html, extracted the tar file and pasted the contents of the folder into `c:\Spark` directory.

After that I have configured the environment variable for spark and jdk accordingly, but I am getting this error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm *almost* sure that your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable contains a space that breaks `spark-shell`. Please re-install Java to a directory with no spaces in the path.

---

You can see the relevant piece of code in [bin/spark-class2.cmd](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/spark-class2.cmd#L26) that `spark-shell` executes on Windows under the covers (through [bin/spark-submit2.cmd](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/spark-submit2.cmd#L27) shell script):

```
if "x%1"=="x" (
```

So when `spark-class2.cmd` substitutes `%1` to a path with a space (or something similar) it ends up as:

```
if "x"Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45""=="x" (
```

that gives the error due to too many double quotes.

The mystery is how does the `JAVA_HOME` end up in this place. I can't seem to find the reason, but that's what we see here.

Comment: Also check for %SPARK_HOME% ... it should not have "white space" in it's path.

Comment: I am using windows10 (unfortunately) and it is automatically installed under the Program Filesx86 folder. Then I re-installed and created a Java file under C:/ and defined the JAVA_HOME path as C:/Java and it resolved.

Answer (score 9):

I resolved this error by using a short hand like "Progra~1" which is a short hand for "Program Files (x86)".

C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_161

Answer (score 7):

You can see this issue when your Java home set like following in windows

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin
```

Issue here is space in "Program Files (x86)"
If you add double quotes will not work on window 10

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin"
```

You need to copy Java into outside Program Files (x86) then it should work

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried uninstalling the previous versions of java, installing the new version in default path i.e. in C:\Program Files\Java.. but still it did not work. 
By looking at the error I tried to add double quotes in the environment variable for JAVA_HOME path but still it did not work. 
**Then I finally re-installed  the same version in C:\Java.. and it worked.** I don't know why it was not working under "C:\Program Files\Java.." even after adding double quotes, so that is why I am posting my findings and resolution as it is. *If someone can provide me the explanation then it will be great.*

Comment: space in Program Files folder name

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the white spaces in the path of Spark and Java.
You can remove the white spaces in path by using the shorthand method to write "Program Files" as "Progra~1".
I had the same issue and it got resolved by above method.

Answer (score -1):

you should set java path in **spark-env.sh** file inside spark conf directory

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Comment: I am new to spark, I can't find spark-env.sh file exactly, I can see spark-env.sh.template in the config directory and it reads " This file is sourced when running various Spark programs.# Copy it as spark-env.sh and edit that to configure Spark for your site." So I copied it and added export statement but still it does not work.