# '""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file - spark shell

Tags: apache-spark

I'm getting an error while running spark-shell

'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need quotes around "C:\ Program Files..." because of the space in the string.

Comment: thanks that was a big help.... this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066854/why-does-spark-shell-fail-with-c-program-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal) helped as well -

Answer (score 1):

I *suspect* that you installed Java to a directory with a space so `JAVA_HOME` breaks `spark-shell` script on Windows.

Make sure you install Java to a directory with no space in the path.

---

The other option would be to set `JAVA_HOME` to the same value but wrapped with double quotes, e.g.

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"
```

That will likely lead to the other issue on Windows that was answered in [Why does spark-shell fail with "was unexpected at this time"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44027151/1305344) that's simply to re-install Java to a directory with no space in the path.

---

The thing I could not check out yet would be to wrapped `JAVA_HOME` using single quotes (not double quotes). That in theory would help pass the line with comparison to `"x"`.

---

p.s. Yes, that's a copy of my answer to [Why does spark-shell fail with "is not recognized as an internal or external command" on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44066854/1305344), but given the mentioned question has no answers approved it's not possible to mark this one as a duplicate.