# Why does spark-shell fail with “was unexpected at this time”? - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, environment-variables

I have a little issue when trying to run **PySpark**. 
I have the following error when launching the command 
`pyspark —master local[2]:`

```
\PySpark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin.. was unexpected at this time.
```

[command line to run pyspark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6q1S.png)

I have reinstalled Java in a folder without spaces, set `JAVA_HOME` variable to `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181` and added the path `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` on top of my windows path but I still have the same error.

Would anyone have any clue about this issue?

It would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Could it be the setting for Pyspark setx PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON ipython
setx PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS notebook. To setup I am refering to https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c , I have used the tutorial before on my laptop and it did work. For Anaconda I am using https://www.anaconda.com/download/ python 3.6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027151/why-does-spark-shell-fail-with-was-unexpected-at-this-time

Comment: Hi Sade, I exactly followed the tutorial on Medium and tried to resolve it following the stackoverflow issue but nothing conclusive on my side unfortunately..

Comment: Thanks Mick I resolved mine issues shortly afterwards. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633549/pyspark-anaconda3-envs-xgboost-python-exe-was-unexpected-at-this-time